# Next.JS-Prisma-Typescript app: generic function error when used with Prisma client

Tags: typescript, next.js, prisma

I am building a Next.JS app with Typescript and Prisma. One part of the app will take data from remote API and copy it to the local database (i.e. local database is being synchronised to the remote api). Since I have several API endpoints I need to copy locally, I decided to make a generic function, but I have some issues with Typescript. Here's the code

```js
import { Prisma, PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
import { catalogApi } from './axios';

interface SyncOptions<T> {
  endpoint: string;
  model: keyof PrismaClient;
  compareFn: (remoteItem: T, localItem: T) => boolean;
}

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export async function syncData<T>({
  endpoint,
  model,
  compareFn,
}: SyncOptions<T>) {
  const remoteData = await catalogApi.post(endpoint);

  const localData = await prisma[model].findMany();

  // compare remote and local data and make them sync
}
```

In the following code, findMany method is the one that raises error as follows

```
Property 'findMany' does not exist on type '(<V extends "beforeExit">(eventType: V, callback: (event: V extends "query" ? QueryEvent : V extends "beforeExit" ? () => Promise<void> : LogEvent) => void) => void) | ... 30 more ...'.
```

However, if I replace a `model` prop with a hardcoded string the error vanishes (provided that table exists in the generated Prisma Client.

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated. Thank you!